# Adding component to container doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs

I could hardly found an easier example but for some unknown reason i have problems with this few lines of code. I dynamically create buttons and add them to my container to the end.

I don't know why but only the first button is added. Please help

Code:

```
var buttonCount = this.getFoldersContainer().query('button').length;
var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button');

button.id = 'folderButton' + record.get('id');
button.setText(record.get('name') + " >>");

console.debug('count');
console.debug(buttonCount);

this.getFoldersContainer().insert(buttonCount,button);
```

I created a new blank project with only this functionality and it works fine. I don't have a clue what could be causing this in my existing project.

Comment: [insert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-insert) method inserts component at specified index, to add multiple components use [add](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-add) method

Comment: Sorry but your comment isn't very helpful. I need the insert method

Comment: You are giving insert index as button length, which will insert at the end of container & `add` method will also add the component the end

Comment: The add component is adding elements to the start. At least in my case and only one containers with 'auto' layout.

Comment: There's not enough information here. You need to post a test case.

Comment: Looking at the example, button is a single component, so there would only be one button added, the code doesn't show an attempt to add more than one button.

Comment: the code is situated in a button click handler

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: I don't know what else to post

Comment: A runnable test case that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should be sure that all buttons get a application wide unique id!
Next is that the id should be present at construction time of the button (in your case it will not be critical but I recommend it). It makes no sense when you are saying that `add()` would insert at the beginning, because it always insert at the end!

```
// ....getFoldersContainer().query('button').length; // count all the items!!
// you may do a check if the id is unique while debugging
if(Ext.getCmp('folderButton' + record.get('id')) != null)
    console.error('Id duplicated! >> ','folderButton' + record.get('id'))
var ct = this.getFoldersContainer(),
    itemCount = ct.items.getCount(), 
    button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {text:record.get('name') + " >>",id:'folderButton' + record.get('id')});

ct.insert(itemCount > 0 ? --itemCount : itemCount ,button);
// if you just want to insert at the end you will be fine with 
// ct.add(button);
```

Comment: The id's were causing the problems